# Extract array keys and values as variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

As you know, Codeigniter is a great PHP framework, I'm trying to make my own framework. Here is a problem. I really like the `$data` functionality in Codeigniter and I want to make it happen in my framework. Question is, how it works.  Here is what it does :

1. you make a array like this :

   ```
   $data['title']= 'My Name';
   ```
2. then you can use this variable like this in view :

   ```
   $title ;
   ```

How I can make a variable like `$data` ?

Comment: I like when people try to create their own stuff!. You want to use your  data variable in views only, right?

Comment: 1) "$data functionality" LOL 2) check how CI does it. the whole source code is there...

Comment: This is not Just for view ... in codeigniter you male the $data['title'] = 'My name'; and then in nest line you use it like this : echo $title; and this is what confused me.

Comment: `when we pass the variable into the $data array inside a controller, We can use that variable exactly after passing it to $data array in controller at the following lines without doing any thing else and without calling any other modules`. *NO!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is turning array keys into variables.
There's one in-built function given to do this.

[extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) - **Import variables into the current symbol table from an array**

```
$data['x'] = "Value";
extract($data,  EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, null);
echo $x;
```

Go through docs and explore how you want to use it.

Comment: I know this my friend ... Problem is here .... How to make the $data variable do all these stuff itself ... without calling any function directly from us, because this is what CI ( codeigniter ) did it.

Comment: @user3492977 CI does this for you. Go through `system\core`Loader.php` and look in `_ci_load` function. You'll see they have used `extract`. As you are writing framework you need mechanism to load views. While doing that you can use this function as they did or better find another way of loading views. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, and also don't write your own framework if you are struggling with this question.

But I think what you are asking is how does CI access the variables in $data (without $data['var_name'];) ?

So if you pass:

```
$data = array("title" => "a page title");
```

in your view you can just . Is that your question - how to do that?

it is simple.

```
function view($data=array(),$file="your-view-file.php") {
extract($data); 
include($file);
}
```

because extract is in the same scope as the include().

Honestly though, just go through the CI files and work this stuff out...